# Tkinter label not updating when using update_idletask()

Tags: python, tkinter

My label isn't updating even though I'm running update_idletask() after changing my variable by using tkinters set() function.

Here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
from pygame import mixer
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

mixer.init()

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless=new")
# start web browser
driver=webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

# get source code
driver.get("http://192.168.2.106:30083/")

# Login
time.sleep(5)
element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="id_dialogContainer"]/sh-dialog/sh-body/div[1]/sh-filter-input/input')
element.send_keys("BOT")
element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

root = tk.Tk()

x=1
def scan():
    global x
# Update Var/Label
    var = tk.StringVar()
    var.set('...')
    main_label = tk.Label(root, text=var.get())
    main_label.pack()
    while True:
        x += 1
        status = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/sh-frame/div[1]/div/sh-bottom-zone/sh-activity-bar/sh-activity-bar-basic/sh-btn/div')
        var.set(status.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
        main_label = tk.Label(root, text=f"{var.get()} {str(x)}")
        print(f"{var.get()} {str(x)}")
        root.update_idletasks()
        if status == "Kein Papier":
            mixer.music.load('Kein Papier.mp3')
            time.sleep(0.1)
            mixer.music.play()
            time.sleep(60)
        elif status == "Papierstau":
            mixer.music.load('Papierstau.mp3')
            time.sleep(0.1)
            mixer.music.play()
            time.sleep(60)
        elif status == "Abdeckung geöffnet":
            mixer.music.load('Abdeckung geöffnet.mp3')
            time.sleep(0.1)
            mixer.music.play()
            time.sleep(60)
        elif status == "Ausgabefach voll":
            mixer.music.load('Ausgabefach voll.mp3')
            time.sleep(0.1)
            mixer.music.play()
            time.sleep(60)
        elif status == "Tonervorrat leer":
            mixer.music.load('Tonervorrat leer.mp3')
            time.sleep(0.1)
            mixer.music.play()
            time.sleep(60)
        else:
            time.sleep(5)

root.after(1, scan)
root.mainloop()
```

I tried to update using update_idletask(), and verified that my loop is working and that it's updating my var by printing.
I also tried using pack() but that only creates new labels instead of updating the already existing label.
I tried multiple solutions I found in this forum but I think I'm implementing them in a wrong way (just like update_idletask())

I just want to update the main label but cant put my finger on whats going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you created new label with the new text and the new label is invisible, so the original label is not updated.

You need to use `main_label.config(text=...)` to update the original label instead of creating new one:

```py
def scan():
    ...
    while True:
        x += 1
        status = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/sh-frame/div[1]/div/sh-bottom-zone/sh-activity-bar/sh-activity-bar-basic/sh-btn/div')
        var.set(status.get_attribute('innerHTML'))
        # use .config() instead of creating new label
        main_label.config(text=f"{var.get()} {str(x)}")
        print(f"{var.get()} {str(x)}")
        root.update_idletasks()
        ...
```

Note that it is not recommended to use while loop in the main thread of a tkinter application.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, everything works now!

I've read that it is not recommended to use a while loop in the main thread of a tkinter application, but didn't quite understand the benefit of using threading over just running it in the mainloop. (As long as the program doesnt get more complicated than mine of course)

Comment: As the while loop will make `scan()` never return, so tkinter `mainloop()` does not get back the control to handle pending updates and events.  Even though you have called `.update_idletasks()`, but it does not perform all the tasks inside `mainloop()`.  Actually the most not recommended is to call `time.sleep()` in a tkinter application.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the clarification. 
Guess I'll try to rewrite my code without using a while loop and without using time.sleep() but that will require some research on my end.

really appreciate the help.